# How to get error 403 internet explorer subcodes

Tags: java

I've this code in Java 8

```
String u = "https://test.com?WSDL";
URL url = new URL(u);
System.out.println("Link: " + u);
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
System.out.println("After url connection");

con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
con.connect();

BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
String input;
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(input);
}
br.close();
```

And I get Error 403 forbidden when I connect to a ii's web service. How can I get Internet explorer subcode error (es. 403.1  execute access forbidden, 403.2  Read access forbidden)?

Comment: What are internet explorer subcodes? Is that a thing? 403.1 is not part of the http standard.

Comment: The Http standard defines status codes to be integers so 403.1 etc. would not even be possible. If you get something like this it's probably part of the response body or a response header.